# Categorize questions in Sharepoint online survey

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, survey, survey-list

I have requirement to categorize the questions (ex: Network,System etc..) in Sharepoint survey. Based on the responses i need to work on responses of users to generate report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create several survey lists based on different question categories.

Or you can export all responses to excel and divide fields into several categories.

Comment: I need to send survey link to users in my organization. I cannot send multiple survey links.